# How do I create a function for adding two matrices? What will it return?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, matrix

So for my homework I have to create a function for adding two matrices, the numbers are given by the user, and I think I have the function somewhat down, I just have no idea what to return because I know you can't return an array, so I tried making a variable to set it equal to but it's not working? Can someone help me out with this?

This is the part I'm stuck on:

```
int add_matrix(int a[][10], int b[][10], int c[][10], int Anum_rows, int Anum_cols)
{
    int matrix_total = c[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < Anum_rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Anum_cols; ++j) {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
        c[i][j] = matrix_total;
    }
    return matrix_total;
}
```

The last `j` in the `c` array is underlined with red also in visual studio.

Comment: Hint: Build a class to model a matrix. Then overload the `+` operator appropriately. Job done.

Comment: Do you know about classes?

Comment: Yeah, I do. But I don't think for this homework assignment we have to make a class. Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: There is but it involves manual dynamic memory management and that's not a route you should use if you can avoid it.

Comment: You are returning your matrix in the third argument to the function. However, your use of matrix_total makes no sense. First, `c[i][j] = matrix_total` should not even compile, second, it makes no sense

Comment: @NathanOliver, not at all. Look at the function signature. It is clear the result is returned in the third argument.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Okay, so that means this function doesn't need to return anything? Can I just set it to void?

Comment: @SergeyA Yeah, it' s not letting me compile, and I figured it didnt make sense, but I just have no clue on what to return?

Comment: You are [obsessed with primitives](https://testing.googleblog.com/2017/11/obsessed-with-primitives.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already does what it needs, it stores the resulting matrix in `c`, which, since arrays are passed as pointers, will still contain the updated values when `add_matrix()` returns.  You just have extra code in the function, which should really not be needed to complete the matrix add operation:

```
void add_matrix(int a[][10], int b[][10], int c[][10], int Anum_rows, int Anum_cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Anum_rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Anum_cols; ++j) {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Good point about `Anum_cols`.  There is no need to pass in the number of columns when it is specified in the argument definition and it could lead to future errors.

```
#define NUM_COLS 10

void add_matrix(int a[][NUM_COLS], int b[][NUM_COLS], int c[][NUM_COLS], int Anum_rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Anum_rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; ++j) {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if the number of columns (`Anum_cols`) is not 10?

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help!!